# Creating a new row in a MySQL database filled with a number

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with 1200 records but now I have a problem...

I need to create a new field called `index` each row containing numbers 1-1200.

Typing these in manually would take a while and I would really prefer a query to do this if possible

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update table x set index=id; given you have id as autoincrement value

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the best way to do it for large numbers of records, but you're dealing with a small number here. You could create a new table and copy the old data into it:

```
CREATE TABLE my_new_table LIKE my_old_table;
ALTER TABLE my_new_table ADD COLUMN (index INT AUTO_INCREMENT ...) FIRST;
INSERT INTO my_new_table (field1, field2, field3, ....)
  SELECT (field1, field2, field3, ...) FROM my_old_table;
```

Then drop the old table and rename the new one.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a SPROC with a loop and use the value of a counter to insert the value.